# appending SVG string to dom

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I'm trying to append a string of svg elements to the dom. This is my setup.

```
var oFragment = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
oFragment += '<g><path id="note-'+i+'" d="M 6,3 84,6  c 0,0 -6,76 14,91  L 58,97 19,89  c 0,0 -24,-5 -13,-86 z" style="fill:#ffc835;" /></g> ';
}
```

Here is what i tried. It gives the following error: "parseXML is not defined"

```
var oSVG = document.getElementById("svg-wall").getSVGDocument();
var oNotes = oSVG.getElementById('notes');
oNotes.appendChild(parseXML(oFragment, document));
```

So my question is: what am i doing wrong and is this even the best way to append a svg string to the dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a free function called `parseXML` (are you missing some functions?).

And since you're dealing with DOM anyway, just not directly insert the elements with DOM?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
   var path = document.createElement("path");
   path.setAttribute("id", "note-" + i);
   ...
   var g = document.createElement("g");
   g.appendChild(path);
   oNotes.appendChild(g);
}
```

Comment: thx! ok i will do it that way. i was hoping for a quicker shorter solution like innerHTML or html() in jquery. There is a root element im inserting it in a <g>.

Comment: @Wieringen: No you're creating 10 `<g>`'s.

Comment: i know but oNotes is a g with the id notes

Comment: @Wieringen: Ah so it's `<g><g><path.../></g><g>...</g></g>`? I think that's fine then.

Comment: Yep :) it works!!! only i needed to replace createElement() with createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

Answer (score 1):

[parseXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/svgudom.html#svg__SVGGlobal) is part of [SVG Tiny 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/), but the SVGGlobal interface methods are not supported in any web browsers at the moment AFAIK. It's entirely possible to implement it using other technologies however. If you look at the bottom of this blogpost of mine, [SVG at the movies take 2](http://my.opera.com/MacDev_ed/blog/2007/11/21/svg-at-the-movies-take-two), you'll find a simple [wrapper script that implements parseXML](http://files.myopera.com/MacDev_ed/svgvideo/udomImpl.js) (should work fine in opera, firefox and webkit). For examples of this script being used have a look at the source of the demos in that blogpost.